# Spark RDD to update

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming, hadoop2, indexedrdd

I am loading a file from HDFS into a `JavaRDD` and wanted to update that `RDD`. For that I am converting it to `IndexedRDD` (https://github.com/amplab/spark-indexedrdd) and I am not able to as I am getting `Classcast Exception`.
Basically I will make key value pair and update the key. `IndexedRDD` supports update. Is there any way to convert ?

```
JavaPairRDD<String, String> mappedRDD =  lines.flatMapToPair( new PairFlatMapFunction<String, String, String>()
    {
        @Override
        public Iterable<Tuple2<String, String>> call(String arg0) throws Exception {

            String[] arr = arg0.split(" ",2);
            System.out.println( "lenght" + arr.length);
             List<Tuple2<String, String>> results = new ArrayList<Tuple2<String, String>>();
             results.addAll(results);
            return results;
        }
    });        

    IndexedRDD<String,String> test = (IndexedRDD<String,String>) mappedRDD.collectAsMap();
```

Comment: which version of spark are you using?

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
   <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
   <version>1.4.1</version>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

The `collectAsMap()` returns a `java.util.Map` containing all the entries from your `JavaPairRDD`, but nothing related to Spark. I mean, that function is to collect the values in one node and work with plain Java. Therefore, you cannot cast it to `IndexedRDD` or any other `RDD` type as its just a normal `Map`.

I haven't used `IndexedRDD`, but from the examples you can see that you need to create it by passing to its constructor a `PairRDD`:

```
// Create an RDD of key-value pairs with Long keys.
val rdd = sc.parallelize((1 to 1000000).map(x => (x.toLong, 0)))
// Construct an IndexedRDD from the pairs, hash-partitioning and indexing
// the entries.
val indexed = IndexedRDD(rdd).cache()
```

So in your code it should be:

```
IndexedRDD<String,String> test = new IndexedRDD<String,String>(mappedRDD.rdd());
```

Comment: Tried this its a compile time error says -  The constructor IndexedRDD<String,String>(JavaPairRDD<String,String>) is undefined

Comment: Mmmm try `new IndexedRDD<String,String>(mappedRDD.rdd());`

Comment: Same compile time error Constructor not defined for this,  not working

Comment: Then I guess you can't use it in Java yet.

Comment: You can't update any kind of RDD. It's a immutable data structure, whether it's in Scala or Java. I haven't tried the IndexedRDD tought yet